# Number of mappers very less for 9 GB Data

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have 9 GB data which has lots of small files lesser than 64 MB block size. I have cluster level block setting as 512 MB. But I have copied this data alone with 64 MB block setting. When I run my pig script with job level hadoop block size as 64 MB , it allocated 20 mappers for this job. I also verified the job.xml having setting as block size as 64 MB. When I reexecute my pig script with cluster level setting as 64 MB, it allocates 160 mappers.

My concern is why it allocates only 20 mappers when I set it in job level. Any idea ?

Comment: Do you have `pig.maxCombinedSplitSize` set?  If so, it will combine small files up to that size before execution.

Comment: @brandon.bell I haven't set that property. But why there is a difference in number of mappers when block size is set in job level and cluster level? It has to be allocate same number of mappers in both the cases right.

Comment: To clarify, you've set the 9GB of data to use 64MB blocks?  The number of mappers you get is dependent on the number of splits.  Pig however does some combining of files if pig.splitCombination is set to true (default).

Comment: @brandon.bell Yes I have copied the 9 GB data with block size property as 64 MB. in both the cases pig will combine the input. but why the splits are different in case1: setting block size as 64 MB in job level case2: setting block size as 64 MB in cluster level. Does it not use the block size set in job level?